# Check if there is an array if not create/add one while increasing the size of the array

Tags: java

I am following a java course and for an assignment. I am supposed to create a bank application.

I have already created all the classes I need.

[image]

This is the UML:

[image: UML]

This is what I am suppose to do:

> Now create a BankAccountService class as in the above diagram. As you
> may have already done noted, we provide a method "addBankAccount" in
> this class. This method accepts as parameter a BankAccount object and
> stores it in the account array. Make sure the account's property
> cannot be used from outside the class. In the addBankAccount method,
> you are going to add the following logic: Check if the account array
> really exists. If this does not exist, we will create an array. You
> can decide how big you want to make the array, make sure you have
> enough space to store all the accounts you want to make in your
> practice. Add the array to the array.

This is what I already have:

```
package BankProject;

public class BankAccountService {



    private void AddBankAccount(BankAccount account[]) {
        if (account == null || account.length == 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < account.length; i++ ){
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My question is how can I connect the array from Person to this class?
The program is supposed to check if the array exists and add an account + increase the size but java sees the account[] I added as null.
Did I do something wrong?
I also tried to add `public class BankAccountService extends Person{` but this did not help how I thought it would be.

Could you guys point me in the right direction?

Comment: your method accepts an array of BankAccount, it should only accept a single BankAccount, not an array, let's start there

Answer (score 0):

I think you misinterpreted something. The BankAccountService should hold an array of BankAccounts. Like the UML shows, the method to store accounts has the following interface:

```
public void addBankAccount(BankAccount account);
```

**Note: I used only fields stated in the uml diagram. I would never implement it that way.**

```
public class BankAccountService
{
  private BankAccount[] accounts;

  public void addBankAccount(final BankAccount account)
  {
    if (accounts == null)
    {
      accounts = new BankAccount[10];
    }

    int index = 0;

    while (accounts[index] != null)
    {
      index++;

      if (index >= accounts.length)
      {
        accounts = Arrays.copyOf(accounts, accounts.length + 10);
      }
    }

    accounts[index] = account;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Stephan, I have one question. Can i use private instead of public? we are suppose to do this in our assignment.


`Make sure the account's property cannot be used from outside the class`

Comment: Since the BankAccount array is private it is not accessible from outside of the class. And the addBankAccount method is stated public in the UML diagram.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what your question is. But A **BankAccount** belongs to a **Person** so you have the attribute **Person** in class **BankAccount** and a Person can have multiple BankAccounts, again which is what you have in your **Person** class (**BankAccounts**[]).

So if you want the Person object in your Service class, you can get it from the **BankAccount** object. There is no need for **Person** class to extend from **BankAccount**.

```
package BankProject;

public class BankAccountService {

    private BankAccount[] accounts;

    private void AddBankAccount(BankAccount account) {
        Person person = account.person;
        BankAccounts[] accountsHeld = person.accounts;

        if (accounts == null) {
            accounts = new BankAccount[accountsHeld.length];
        }
        
        int index = 0;
        for(account: accountsHeld){
            accounts[index] = account;
            index += 1;
        }
    }
}
```